# How to script GPPs?

Tags: group-policy, scripting

I'm trying to normalize Item-Level Targeting for several GPPs that I've created. Manually slogging through each one via the GUI is just about the last thing I want to do. The terms tedious and error-prone come to mind.

I've been researching a way to script this, but alas I'm coming up empty.

Is there a way to get a list of GPPs that have ILT turned on, to include an output of each ILT configuration?

Comment: GPP is just an xml file last time I check.  Powershell can easily rip through an xml file.  You can locate the xml file in the GP folder in Sysvol.  Just find the guild for the GP you want to modify.

Comment: **@EricC.Singer** Sounds good, will do. Thanks.

Comment: if you need help parsing XML, let me know.

Comment: **@EricC.Singer** I appreciate the offer. Let's see how things shake out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To this day, there is no suitable way to do what you want using built-in Windows commands (I believe). There are 3rd party tools you can buy for that.

One OOTB way would be to export all GPOs to XML and then filter the output to your liking.

`Get-GPOReport -all -ReportType XML -Path c:\temp\gporeport.xml` for example.

This is by no means pretty (or practical, really).

Another way would be to export every GPO to it's own report and then filter these files:

```
Get-GPO -All | %{
     Get-GPOReport -name $_.displayname -ReportType xml -path "c:\temp\gpos\"+$_.displayname+".xml")
 }
```

You can also export them in HTML and then filter for the strings you need.

This is not meant as a correct and/ or complete answer, but it's a bit too long for a comment.

Comment: That'll work, thanks. Upon some spelunking through the XML, I've discovered that each exported GPP is stored in the `<ExtensionData />` element, with any ILTs discoverable as descendant nodes. The ILT nodes are `<q[n]:filters />`, where `[n]` is the positional identifier in the 1-based global list. It'll take a little doing, but I can get this. I appreciate the lead.